# Cyclic dependency in graph error during migration when using existing MSSQL Database

Tags: django

I have connected Django to MS SQL server 2017. But i am getting the following error during migration

> django.utils.topological_sort.CyclicDependencyError: Cyclic dependency in graph:

I am seeing that this model which was generated after running `python manage.py inspectdb` is the one causing this. What could be wrong?

```
class Djangomodel(models.Model):
    id = models.OneToOneField('self', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Id', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `OneToOneField` is basically a `ForeignKey` with `unique=True` (but with a few more differences to make using the ORM more easier). A foreign key to `self` literally means a foreign key to some other entry in the same table. A foreign key to `self` being the **primary key** doesn't make sense and is basically impossible and absurd.

I don't know how `inspectdb` ended up making such a field. Anyway you should change this field to reflect how your primary key actually is. Mostly it would be along the lines of an `IntegerField` or an `AutoField` (basically an auto incrementing integer field) or in some cases a `UUIDField`:

```py
class Djangomodel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```